# In lxde local path is prepended when a hyperlink is clicked

Tags: lxde

Whenever I click on a hyperlink presented within a software the link seems to be modified. Let's say software X presents a link to its online documentation, e.g. https://www.coolsoft.org/doc/manual.html

I get an error message in a window marked with a yellow folder in the upper left. The error message will read:

```
/home/myuser/'somepath'/http:/www.coolsoft.org/doc/manual.html: file or directory not found
```

'somepath' seems to be the working directory of program X in many cases. Note that the full link which is obviously nonsense misses a / after http: or https:
The small folder symbol in the corner of the error message makes me think, that the issue is related to lxde's file browser.

However there are exceptions. When I click links in messages in Thunderbird, the link opens flawlessly in firefox.

How can I fix this?

**Update**

Being asked for a specific example.
Today I used Anki. Anki was installed via packet manager (xbps). Anki showed a link with information to look up. It triggers the error message:

```
/home/ariser/.local/share/Anki2/Benutzer 1/collection.media/http:/ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#using-decks-appropriately: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

This is the original error message in German.

Comment: hm, interesting! Since this might be happening on the boundary of *specific* programs and your *specific* session manager LXDE, it'd probably be easiest to talk about a specific example that actually triggers this behaviour – so far we only know one that does *not*! So, picking any one, in which program does this happen?

Comment: Do you get the same error with correctly formed URLs? I.e., with URLs that have `http://` (double slash) instead of `http:/` (single slash).

Comment: @Kusalananda I can't test it with correctly formed URLs because all URLs from any program get mangled this way. Just for testing I opened FreeCAD and tried to open the homepage via the help menu of the program and the URL is crippled again: /home/ariser/http:/www.freecadweb.org I don't think it's the fault of the programs supplying the URL.

Comment: Wow, interesting... Does running `xdg-open https://example.com` also fail?

Comment: My current guess is that something installed a URL handler for http:, which was maybe designed to handle a few http URLs itself and pass through the rest to a browser, and that thing is badly broken

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes xdg-open results the same way. And again miraculously one of the slashes removed. i.e. `xdg-open https://www.tagesschau.de` brings up `/home/ariser/https:/www.tagesschau.de: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden` Funny.

Comment: wow! OK, then, who does this? What does `xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler https` say?

Comment: @MarcusMüller userapp-Firefox-VHCIT0.desktop

Comment: now, I don't know void linux (this is void Linux, right?) well enough, but for me that's just `firefox.desktop`, which means /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop is consulted on how to open https URLs, which in turn just runs `firefox %u` (the `%u` gets replaced with the URL). Do you have a firefox.desktop containing an `Exec=firefox %u` line? Can you try to `locate userapp-Firefox-VHCIT0.desktop`, and check whether it does something strange in the `Exec=` line?

Comment: @MarcusMüller mlocate yields `/home/ariser/.local/share/applications/userapp-Firefox-VHCIT0.desktop` and within that I found `Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox %u` So nothing which could explain why the URL gets mutilated. I think the error message could be issued by PCManFM. Perhaps the URL is not recognized as URL at all but gets interpreted as a local path from the very beginning.

Comment: @Ariser I considered that possibility, that's why we ruled it out through `xdg-open https://example.com`! Now we're down to debugging where the hell things go wrong, in the source code (I'm *so here* for this kind of bug hunting!)

Comment: @Ariser 1. `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox https://example.com` does work, right? (I really think it ought, but I've stopped ruling out things!)

Comment: 2. if it does work, we need to debug `xdg-open`; if it doesn't, we need to debug that script.

Comment: @MarcusMüller firefox is opening the sample domain correctly, xdg-open can't interfere here, at least. That could explains why Thunderbird manages to open URLs in firefox. Thunderbird most likely looks up if FF is installed and calls it directly then :)